# Find shortest path from (0,0) to (N,N) in matrix using memorization to cache the result

Tags: java, algorithm, caching, data-structures

I need to find a shortest path in a N*N matrix maze from (0,0) to (N,N), assume 1 is passable, 0 is not, 3 is destination, use memorization to cache the result. The following is my solution, which can correctly find the shortest path.

But the cache is not working correctly. It only stores the first path it has found. How can I fix this?

```
public static class MazeResult {
    public boolean solved;
    public List<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
    public int steps = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    public MazeResult(boolean isSolved) {
        solved = isSolved;
    }
}

static Map<String, MazeResult> cache = new HashMap<String, MazeResult>();
public static MazeResult solveMaze(int[][] m, int r, int c, List<String> path, HashSet<String> visited) {
    if (r < 0 || r >= m.length || c < 0 || c >= m[0].length)
        return new MazeResult(false);
    String cell = r + "" + c + "";
    if (m[r][c]==0 || visited.contains(cell))
        return new MazeResult(false);
    if (m[r][c] == 3) {
        MazeResult ret = new MazeResult(true);
        ret.res = new ArrayList<String>(path);
        ret.res.add(cell);
        ret.steps = path.size() + 1;
        return ret;
    }
    if (cache.containsKey(cell))
        return cache.get(cell);

    path.add(cell);
    visited.add(cell);
    MazeResult ret = new MazeResult(false), temp = new MazeResult(false);

    temp = solveMaze(m, r, c+1, path, visited);
    compareResult(temp, ret);

    temp = solveMaze(m, r, c-1, path, visited);
    compareResult(temp, ret);

    temp = solveMaze(m, r+1, c, path, visited);
    compareResult(temp, ret);

    temp = solveMaze(m, r-1, c, path, visited);
    compareResult(temp, ret);

    path.remove(path.size()-1);
    visited.remove(cell);

    cache.put(cell, ret);
    return ret;
}

private static void compareResult(MazeResult temp, MazeResult ret) {
    if (temp.solved) {
        if (temp.steps < ret.steps) {
            ret.res = temp.res;
            ret.steps = temp.steps;
        }
        ret.solved = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I have figured it out. Instead of using top-down approach, I should use bottom-up when adding cells to the result list.

Comment: To improve the future value of this Q&A, can you [edit] your answer and elaborate a bit? Or, if you don't think this Q&A has much future value, you could probably delete the question.